# How to convert a string in an array to lowercase

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have two arrays of strings and Im trying to compare strings from them. However, one string in an array has the first letter capitalized where as the string the other doesn't. Any thoughts?

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Use trasform to make capital letter for complete string. Convert both array string to capital before comparison.
    std::string s("hello");
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
                   [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return std::toupper(c); });

Comment: You should produce some minimal, complete, reproducible attempt, including test input, and result output.

Comment: Also, please  review the std::string methods available to you ...  consider a) operator ==(s1, s2)  (i.e. if (s1 == s2) { ..when equal action.. }  and b)   if(0 == compare(s1, s2)) { .. when equal action.. }

Comment: "Any thoughts?" -- if 1st letter of the two strings are NOT the same, then the strings are NOT equal.  Perhaps your requirements are not well understood?  Did you mis-state your problem?

Answer (score 1):

> I have two arrays of strings and Im trying to compare strings from
>   them.

You can use [`std::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal)  for two strings like following:

```
bool compareStrings(const string& a, const string& b)
{
    return std::equal(a.cbegin(), a.cend(),
                      b.cbegin(), b.cend(),
                      [](const auto& x, const auto& y) {
                          return std::tolower(x) == std::tolower(y);
                      });
}
```

If you have access to boost, you could do:

```
if (boost::iequals(a, b))
{
    // strings are same
}
```